# RSACryptoServiceProvider C# returning keys

Tags: c#, encryption

How to return public and private keys in `RSACryptoServiceProvider`  as strings?

Comment: -1 for storing private keys in a database instead of using Windows/Platform specific key management facilities. Are you going to at least use password protection for the exported keys

Comment: my scenario is diffrance than u think ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to get the private key, but if you do, take a look at the [ExportParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.exportparameters.aspx) method. This will give you all sorts of stuff from the keys. You can also get an XML dump of it from the [ToXmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.toxmlstring.aspx) method.

Comment: what does this return ? public key or private key ? .. actually i need the both !

Comment: Look at the links. Both of the methods take a boolean. Pass true if you want both keys, false if you only want public.

Comment: Thanks Tobias .. so how to provide back the keys when i required to decrypt the text in  a other instance ??

Comment: RSACryptoServiceProvider has a constructor that takes a CSPParameters (which you get from ExportParameters).

Comment: i just required to get the both public and private keys  and store in a database and use in future purposes

Comment: Why the database? Why not use the Windows Crypto Provider?